# p5 js acting differently in their website editor than in my editor

Tags: javascript, rendering, p5.js

I recently started using p5 js and it was working fine until now.
In the online p5 editor on their website, I am running this code:

```
//sketch.js

var cols, rows;
var scl = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400, WEBGL);
  cols = width/scl;
  rows = height/scl;
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  rotateX(PI/3);
  translate(-(width/2), -(height/2));

  for (var y=0; y<rows; y++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (var x=0; x<cols+1; x++) {
      //rect(x*scl, y*scl, scl, scl);
      vertex(x*scl, y*scl);
      vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl);
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

The result would look like this: [image: This is what I want it to look like]

The picture above is exactly what I am trying to render.
However, I copy and paste the exact same code into my editor (I'm using Atom)
and the result I get is this:
[image]
I still get the same shape outline but it should look exactly the same as the first picture with the gridlines but it doesn't and I have no idea why;
In the html file, the script tags have the source for my js file and for p5 js (I copied them from the p5 website

```
//index.html I'm only showing the script tags, not the entire html document
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js'></script>
<script src='sketch.js'></script>
```

If somebody cloud please explain what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: The p5.js editor currently uses `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js`. Does switching to that give you the same result in both places?

Comment: @KevinWorkman The link you provided gave me the result I was looking for in my own code. Thanks very much